# Select from a hierarchy based on a range of ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, tree, hierarchy

I have table holding a hierarchical structure so basically it has 3 columns as :

[image]

What I want is to select from this table by a range of ID's for example :

```
Id IN (1,4,8,18)
```

which results to :

[image]

> In other word a row must come into result set with all of it's parents and children.

How could i solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using CTE:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, ParentID INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, NULL ),
        ( 2, 1 ),
        ( 3, 2 ),
        ( 4, 3 ),
        ( 6, NULL ),
        ( 7, 6 ),
        ( 8, 7 ),
        ( 9, 8 ),
        ( 10, 9 ),
        ( 11, 10 ),
        ( 13, NULL ),
        ( 14, 13 ),
        ( 15, 14 ),
        ( 17, NULL ),
        ( 18, 17 ),
        ( 19, 18 ),
        ( 20, 19 );

WITH    ctep
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    ID IN ( 1, 4, 8, 18 )
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.*
               FROM     @t t
                        JOIN ctep ON t.ParentID = ctep.ID
             ),
        ctec
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    ID IN ( 1, 4, 8, 18 )
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.*
               FROM     @t t
                        JOIN ctec ON t.ID = ctec.ParentID
             )
    SELECT  * FROM    ctep
    UNION
    SELECT  * FROM    ctec
```

Here are 2 CTEs, for getting parents and childs. Finally you union those 2 results in order to get distinct rows.

I had a little bug. Edited...

Answer (score 1):

Split your task into two steps

1. Find top most parent
2. Find all decedents

   ```
   WITH ToTopParent AS
   (
       SELECT Id, ParentId
       FROM yourTable
       WHERE Id IN (1,4,8,18) 

       UNION ALL

       SELECT T.Id, T.ParentId
       FROM ToTopParent TTP
       JOIN yourTable T ON TTP.ParentId = T.Id
   ),
   AllDecedents AS
   (
       SELECT Id, Name, ParentID
       FROM yourTable 
       WHERE id IN (SELECT Id FROM ToTopParent WHERE ParentId IS NULL)

       UNION ALL

       SELECT T.Id, T.Name, T.ParentID
       FROM yourTable T
       JOIN AllDecedents ON T.ParentId = AllDecedents.Id
   )
   SELECT * FROM AllDecedents
   ```

Comment: thanks @qxg . your solution works perfect but there was another correct answer which came sooner

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive common table expression (CTE). It is very good at these kind of tasks. Below I have assumed that `tbl` is the name of your table.

```
WITH UserCTE AS
(

SELECT Id, name, ParentId
FROM tbl
WHERE Id in (1,4,8,18)

UNION ALL

SELECT P.Id, P.name, P.ParentId
FROM UserCTE AS C --- C for child
JOIN tbl AS P --- P for parent
ON C.ParentId = P.Id

)
SELECT Id, name, ParentId
FROM UserCTE;
```

You may also try using

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, name, ParentId
FROM UserCTE;
```

if you notice that certain records are returned more than once.

Comment: It will not work for childs...(1,3,8,18) doesn't selects 4 but 4 is child of 3.

Comment: this solution does not pop out children as well

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I misread, thought the guy wanted just the parents given a set of IDs. If so, of course then another CTE (for the children) could help.